# Custom class name in css binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have an observable array like this:

```
arrayName =  ko.observableArray([
    {name: First Name, type: normal},
    {name: Second Name, type: low},
    {name: Third Name, type: high}]);
```

and want to set my DOM element's class something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayName">
    <div data-bind="text: name"> </div>
    <div data-bind="css: type"> </div>
</div>
```

anybody know how to make it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to actually build the DOM or is the DOM already built and you want to add data-bind to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this :

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uy8xd5e/)

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayName">
<div data-bind="text: name, css: type"> </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var myModel = function() {

   this.arrayName =  ko.observableArray([
     {name: "First Name", type: "normal"},
     {name: "Second Name", type: "low"},
     {name: "Third Name", type: "high"}]);


}




ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

First of all, all your values for classes should be defined in string representation.

You add class (in your example) to the empty div, which doesn't have any content and you can't see it, if i understand you right you should add the class to the same div to which you add name property .

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, only need to add quotes for strings for each property:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: arrayName">
    <div data-bind="text: name"> </div>
    <div data-bind="css: type"> </div>
</div>

<script>
    function vm (){
      this.arrayName =  ko.observableArray([
        {name: "First Name", type: "normal"},
        {name: "Second Name", type: "low"},
        {name: "Third Name", type: "high" }]);         
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
</script>
```